# I am trying to convert 2 modules that use Java8 language features, how do I mimic static/default method behaviour?

Tags: java, java-8, compatibility, backwards-compatibility

I am tasked with migrating 2 separate modules to be compatible with Java 7 compilation and runtime.  I would like to know if I'm taking everything into account (i.e. will there be many future side effects, limitations, etc.).

The modules are called ModuleA and ModuleB, structured like this:

```
ModuleA            <- Runtime Library
   \-pack1      <- This contains ~15 interfaces, ~3 layers of inheritance, and occasionally static/default methods 
   \-pack2      <- This contains some standard implementations of interfaces in package1

ModuleB            <- Main app. Depends on ModuleA
   \-main          <- Classes here call static/default ModuleA.package1.* interface methods a lot
```

ModuleB can change regularly, while ModuleA is proprietary/internal API and unlikely to change. Translation of the source to Java 7 compatibility is a process that's been giving me some trouble.

How I initially planned to do this was by making a static inner class inside of each interface, and migrating the static and default methods inside the inner class, changing all of them `static`. I would mark the (former) default methods after changing the signature/implementation by adding the instance as the *first argument* into the parameter list, and then also adding an annotation `@Default` (so I will know how to translate the implementations in ModuleB). So this:

```
    interface Foo {

        void doFoo(String bar);

        default String toFancyString() {
            return this.toString() + "called from a default method";
        }

        static int getFooDefault() {
            return 0xCAFEBABE;
        }
    }
```

Will get changed to:

```
interface Foo {
    void doFoo(String bar);

    final class Util {

        @Default
        static String toFancyString(Foo impl) {
            return impl.toString() + "called from a default method";
        }
        static int getFooDefault() {
            return 0xCAFEBABE;
        }
    }
}
```

After changing both ModuleA packages, I'd then change ModuleB (at compilation) to the equivalent of changing this:

```
int i = foo.getFooDefault() + 1;
Foo f = bar -> System.out.println(bar);
String fancyString = f.toFancyString();
```

to this:

```
int i = Foo.Default.getFooDefault() + 1;
Foo f = // anonymous class bloat here
String fancyString = Foo.Default.toFancyString(f);
```

**What I'm wondering:**

- How do I mimic interface inheritance when changing ModuleA.package1? Since the methods in `Util` class are all static, I thought about adding all of static methods to subclasses for which there exist superclass methods, and manually call the closest up-the-chain's static method from the subclass static method, but there may be a simpler solution.
- Could there ever a case where this would not compile if I automated the second part (ModuleB - code which may change frequently)?

Lines of code/complexity doesn't matter because I can script most of source transformation. My goal is simply to be able to produce the same exact input/output when running in JRE7 as in 8, **without** using any reflection/duck typing. (Also, I am only worried about the static/default issue, not any new JDK8 APIs)

Comment: Have you considered using an abstract class instead of an interface?

Comment: @shmosel I'd love to explain the exact scenario I'm dealing with but the real reason is I need to have invokedynamic - package1 contains mostly `@FunctionalInterfaces`

Answer (score 2):

migrate jdk-8 to jdk-7 which using default methods/static methods on interface. you can replacing interface with abstract class. then other modules using your migrated module does not need to modify. for example:

```
abstract class Foo {

    public abstract void doFoo(String bar);

    public String toFancyString() {
        return this.toString() + "called from a default method";
    }

    public static int getFooDefault() {
        return 0xCAFEBABE;
    }
}
```

**But**, there is another reason to introduce an abstract class and pull down all static methods to the abstract class when you using java [Proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) api. then let all of your classes which has been implemented `Foo` extends `AbstractFoo`, for example:

```
interface Foo {
    void doFoo(String bar);

    String toFancyString();
}

abstract class AbstractFoo implements Foo {
    public String toFancyString() {
        return this.toString() + "called from a default method";
    }

    static int getFooDefault() {
        return 0xCAFEBABE;
    }
}

class SimpleFoo extends AbstractFoo {
    @Override
    public void doFoo(String bar) {/*todo*/}
}
```

**Note**: other modules need to modify when calling the static method in the second approach due to where the static methods live in was changed.

Comment: Upvoted because clever solution which works, but my project (somewhat experimental) needs to keep SAM types so I can technically still have `invokedynamic` which doesn't work with abstract classes.  I guess it still could work though, but I don't know if it's better than changing to static methods and adding a `Foo` instance to the @Default method arguments and translate (through AST transform or bytecode weave) in the method any `invokevirtual` with target `this` to target the `Foo` argument.  It's good to know that there's multiple ways to do this, thanks for the response!

Comment: Also, I won't be using any reflection such as `Proxy`.  I'm targeting android so reflection is somewhat costly there

Comment: @PrestonGarno Hi, why do you need to keep SAM types? invokedynamic also supported with abstract classes. and if you only want to narrow the interface with SAM you can introduce another interface `IFoo` that only declare `doFoo` method. and let Foo extends/implements `IFoo`.

Comment: I guess I could javap a sample to find out but do you have any source on that? I was under the impression that it wasn't.

Comment: @PrestonGarno due to [@FunctionalInterface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) does not  count methods from `Object`. and `this.toString()` will call `invokevirtual` instruction. could you describe your problem clearly in your question? I'd like to know what you really want.

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty sure you're mistaken.  Abstract classes *necessitate* an instance.  SAM types do not.  When you say "@FunctionalInterface does not count methods from Object. and this.toString() will call invokevirtual instruction", you're not wrong.  However, this is restricted to only java.lang.Object public methods & iface default methods which use `invokeinterface`, AFAIK. @FunctionalInterface is simply an annotation to mark a SAM type.  If you could provide something saying otherwise I'll definitely check it out though!

Comment: @PrestonGarno Sorry, I left for a while. you are right at above comment, but I need to know why abstract classes can't `invokedynamic`? what does your [invokedyanmic](http://wiki.apidesign.org/wiki/InvokeDynamic) mean? maybe we are talking with different situations.

Answer (score 0):

As I am sure you are aware, `@FunctionalInterface` and default implementations in interfaces where introduced in Java 8.  Before this, there was no implementation in the interface...this all had to be done in whatever implemented it.  Generally, I would still call this poor practice.  The idea is if I wanted to ADD methods to an already existing interface, and not break everything that was using it (like forEach on the Lists interface).

That being said, I am not sure there is a straight path going down.  You can either do an Abstract class that has these already implemented, but you can only inherit from one Abstract Class, so this may not work, or the static methods described...but this blow inheritance out of the water.

`@FunctionalInterface` is simple, it just enforces that there is no more than one non-default method in the interface at compile time.  Just remove the annotation, and that should work for Java 7.